# PHP string with link inside

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this Wordpress function:

```
function register_text( $translated ) {
    $translated = str_ireplace('Register',  'REGISTER',  $translated);
    return $translated;
}

add_filter(  'gettext',  'register_text'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'register_text'  );
```

I would like for "REGISTER" to be `<a href="#register"></a> REGISTER`

The question would be I guess: how to add html inside that string.

Thank you and sorry if this is too obvious. Total php newbie here

Comment: Literally place HTML inside the string.

Comment: `return str_ireplace('Register',  '<a href="#register"></a> REGISTER',  $translated);` is a easy simplification to your function code

Comment: It doesn't render the link. Here what I get: https://pasteboard.co/JLk3GBS.png

Comment: If you want to make the word "Register" a link word then you need to **wrap** it in the anchor tag: `<a href="#register">REGISTER</a>` for example

Comment: It may well be worth you actually going away and doing some research and tutorials about the topics you're trying to work on.

Comment: I actually want the anchor tag separate from the word. I'm using it as anchored section to have a direct link to the section in this page.

Answer (score 0):

```
function register_text( $translated ) {
    $translated = str_ireplace('Register',  '<a href="#register"></a> REGISTER',  $translated);
    return $translated;
}
```

Seems that you call the filter function  from inside   `htmlspecialchar()`
thath render the login box also. Check the login template .

Comment: Thank you Mario! But it doesn't render it: https://pasteboard.co/JLk3GBS.png

Comment: This is a function to pretty much replacing the standard 'Register" title to something else. I just want to add an anchor text in front so I can link to this section.